# Php wrong value

Tags: php, html, arrays, xml

I am using the following code. I take some values from an xml, then I use as html option.  I am using almost the same code for the first and second select. First option show in the select menu the right values: http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/anvelope.php, but the other one shows 0. Could somebody to tell me what to do on the "Eficienta combustibil" to show the right values?

```
<form action="anvelope.php" method="post">
<?php
$jante = "http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/feeds/alcarRO_feed.xml";

$xml=simplexml_load_file($jante);

$items = [];
$limitItems = 0;
foreach($xml->Produs as $child)
{
   $marca = (string)$child->Marca;
   if(!isset($items[$marca])) {
       $items[$marca] = [];
   }

   $items[$marca]['sarcina'][] = (int)$child->Sarcina;
   $items[$marca]['eficienta_combustibil'][] = (float)$child->Eficienta_Combustibil;   

}




//SARCINA
$option_arr9 = array_column($items,'sarcina');
function generate_option9($item, $key)
{
    echo "<option value='" . $item . "'>" . $item . "</option>";
}

$options = array_unique($option_arr9[0], SORT_STRING); // You can add array_unique and SORT_NUMERIC here
asort($options);

echo "<select name='sarcina'><option>Sarcina</option>";
array_walk_recursive($options, 'generate_option9');
echo "</select>";




//EFICIENTA COMBUSTIBIL
$option_arr10 = array_column($items,'eficienta_combustibil');
function generate_option10($item, $key)
{
    echo "<option value='" . $item . "'>" . $item . "</option>";
}

$options = array_unique($option_arr10[3], SORT_STRING); // You can add array_unique and SORT_NUMERIC here
asort($options);

echo "<select name='eficienta_combustibil'><option>Eficienta Combustibil</option>";
array_walk_recursive($options, 'generate_option10');
echo "</select>";


?>



</form>
```

Comment: Looking at the source data all the `Eficienta_Combustibil` values are characters from B-G. So trying to convert them to floats (`$items[$marca]['eficienta_combustibil'][] = (float)$child->Eficienta_Combustibil; `) is going to return 0 all the time. Perhaps you should just leave them as string values?

Comment: Thank you! Done! :)